# Making validation in GUI on textfield and setting the Textfield empty after validation

Tags: java, swing, validation

I am creating a simple GUI form in which I have two text filed one for name and other for phone number, I am trying to validate them and setting them empty on clicking on button.
But On clicking on button again the JOptionPane Opened which I doesn't want,please help me for this approach.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Form {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
        final JButton btnOne = new JButton("save");
        final JTextField jname = new JTextField(8);
        final JTextField jphno = new JTextField(8);
        final JLabel lname = new JLabel("Name");
        final JLabel lphno = new JLabel("Phone no");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(58, 192, 126));

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        btnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (jname.getText().length() <= 2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "please enter at    least Three digits");
                }
            }
        });
        btnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (jphno.getText().trim().length() != 10) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                             "Please enter Valid Phone no");
                }
            }
        });
        btnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int j = jphno.getText().length();
                int h = jname.getText().length();
                if (e.getSource() == btnOne && j == 10 && h >= 3) {
                    jname.setText("");
                    jphno.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        jname.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                if (fe.getSource() == jname) {
                    jname.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        jphno.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                if (fe.getSource() == jphno) {
                    jphno.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
// adding components
        frame.setLayout(gbl);
        gbc.anchor = gbc.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 30, 20, 30);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(lname, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(jname, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(lphno, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(jphno, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        frame.add(btnOne, gbc);
        btnOne.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        btnOne.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: You have added three listeners to the button. Why don't you use just one?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding multiple action listeners to the same button. As a result, all of them will fire when the button is pressed. In this instance, it seems like the last listener is being fired first, which resets the data causing the other listeners to complain.

Just combine your code into one action listener.

Or, as suggested by [mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298612/making-validation-in-gui-on-textfield-and-setting-the-textfield-empty-after-vali/16298720#comment23332153_16298720), you may wish to adjust your approach and use a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to validate the contents of your `JTextField`s [on the fly](http://www.coderanch.com/t/610054/GUI/java/Add-DocumentListener-validate-multiple-JTextFields).

Comment: +1 good catch, but direction of answer could be about DocumentListener added to JTextFields, [with this code](http://www.coderanch.com/t/610054/GUI/java/Add-DocumentListener-validate-multiple-JTextFields) by @camickr

Comment: @mKorbel Good idea, I've edited my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: I received a downvote on this - can someone highlight my error?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you - combines all three action listeners into one.

```
btnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //get length of the input fields
            int phoneInputLength = jphno.getText().length();
            int nameInputLength = jname.getText().length();

            //Check the name and phone number are the correct length first
            if (phoneInputLength != 10 && nameInputLength <= 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a name that is at least three characters" +
                                              "\nand enter a valid phone no (10 digits long)");
            } else if (phoneInputLength != 10) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter Valid Phone no");
            } else if (nameInputLength <= 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "please enter at    least Three digits");
            } else {
                jname.setText("");
                jphno.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, you do not need the line:

```
 if (e.getSource() == btnOne)
```

as you are adding an action listener specifically for btnOne component via line:

```
 btnOne.addActionListener
```

I would also do some validation to ensure that the phone number given in the input box contains ONLY digits. something like

```
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(jphno.getText());
    //success - then you can make the text field empty 
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Phone numbers can only contain digits. " +
                                         "Please remove any characters that are not digits!",
                                         "Invalid Phone Number", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```